# Verma modules and delta function

Tags: complex-analysis, representation-theory

What is the relationship between Verma modules and delta functions? Here's the quote from Woit's notes on Lie theory (http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/LieGroups-2012/vermamodules.pdf):

> The subject of "geometric representation theory" relates Verma modules to
>   the geometry of the 
>   flag variety $G/B$. $B$ acts on the left, with a finite number
>   $\lvert W \rvert$ of $B$-orbits (this is the Bruhat decomposition). For $G = SL(2;\mathbb C)$,
>   $G/B = \mathbb CP_1$ and there are two $B$-orbits: the Riemann sphere minus the South
>   pole, and the South pole, of dimension 2 and 0 respectively. Verma modules
>   correspond to delta-function distributions on the $B$-orbits, dual Verma modules
>   to holomorphic functions on the orbits, singular at the boundary.

Is there an analogue of meromorphic functions in this setting? Nevanlinna theory, perhaps? (I ask of Nevanlinna theory to, perhaps, make connections with Vojta's dictionary of some sort)

P.S. This is a very speculative question, so feel free to close it, but I can't think of a better place to ask.

Comment: I suspect you aren't going to get a satisfactory answer here. You might want to try reposting on http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: See also OP's repost [MO:188711](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188711/relationship-between-verma-modules-and-delta-functions) of this question and its answer.